# Fragment Transaction replace() is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to replace a fragment to another with navigation drawer. But it only adds on old fragment. I researched in site questions but I still didn't solve this problem.It's like fragment overlap. Here's my codes;

MainActivity;

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Kamera click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        fragment = new PuanDurumuFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Galeri click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "3.click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Fikstür click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(id);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
    return true;
}
```

content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.example.faksu.myapplication.MainActivity">

<!--    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"-->

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and here is app_bar_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.faksu.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding on fragment? You are adding fragment to backstack.

Comment: What do you mean by this? "But it only adds on old fragment."

Comment: I cant add image. I mean the old fragment is still on screen and new fragment is shown with old fragment. It is like adding not replacing. So i have two fragments in my screen. Old one is background new one is foreground